# While loop doesnt seem to stop in Java when its supposed to

Tags: java

I don't understand why the program doesn't come out of the loop even after 
 the value of variable YoN is entered as "N".

Output:

[image]

code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaLessonFour{
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String YoN = "Y";
        while(YoN != "N")
        {

            System.out.println("inside");
            YoN = s.next();
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: `while (!YoN.equals("N"))`.

Comment: use `.equals()` to compare Strings

Comment: Put `System.out.println(">>" + YoN + "<<");` just after `YoN = s.next();` - that way you will see what is there. I would consider comparing against `Y` not `N`.